# Issue while assigning temp data to hash table in Powershell inside Groovy Script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I am creating a groovy Jenkins pipeline while running PowerShell code inside groovy script.
Below is the code I am trying to run inside Groovy.

```
                    powershell("""

                    \$global:alldistqueue = @()
                    
                    foreach(\$distqueue in \$DISTRIBUTOR_QUEUES)
                    {
                            \$distrow = "" | Select Distributor,QueueName
                            \$distrow.Distributor = "$DISTRIBUTOR_NAME"
                            \$distrow.QueueName = \$distqueue
                            
                            \$global:alldistqueue += \$distrow
                        
                        
                        Write-host "Data \$distrow"

                    }
                        Write-host "\$global:alldistqueue "  """)
```

Issue is I do not get the data in $global:alldistqueue variable in PowerShell  but i checked data is there in $distrow temp variable. Any Idea , Please help on this.

Thanks

Comment: You probably wanna do `Write-host (\$global:alldistqueue |Out-String)` to get the output formatted properly

Comment: Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen, It worked  , But i still don't know why it was not working , it works in PowerShell. Please post this as a answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you expand an array or collection variable in a string expression, PowerShell does a simple `String.Join` operation using the current value of `$OFS` (the "output-field separator") as a separator.

This means that if the default string implementation (the `ToString()` method) for the underlying object type produces empty strings, then your string expression (like `"$global:alldistqueues"`) ends up being all whitespace.

Instead, use the `Out-String` cmdlet to force PowerShell to format and render the object as one big string output using [its own formatting subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.3) - thus bypassing the default `ToString()` output, before passing it to `Write-Host`:

```
Write-Host $($alldistqueue |Out-String)
```

Or, escaped for your Groovy source code:

```
Write-Host \$(\$alldistqueue |Out-String)
```